# reduce the result entry for the command \newtheorem{}{}[]

Tags: errors

when i put it in the code:

```
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
```

I get the following result :
[image]

but I only want to see "**Proposition 1**" while maintaining the order according to the section hashes.

What change can i make ?

An idea please

Comment: Only `\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}`.

Comment: Just to confirm:  You want the proposition numbers to restart at 1 when the section changes.  ???

Comment: yes i want the proposition numbers to restart at 1 when the section changes